# Why does the output format of time vary depending on how I call it

Tags: command-line, bash, time-command

It may be a newbie's question, but I don't understand how this is configured and why the output format of `time` command is different in these two cases:

if used via `time`, the output is three rows with basic info

```
$ time sleep 1

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

then I can check out which binary is used

```
$ which time
/usr/bin/time
```

and call it directly to get output in a completely different format, with much more info

```
$ /usr/bin/time sleep 1
0.00user 0.00system 0:01.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2000maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+77minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

there are no aliases related to `time`

```
$ alias | grep time
$
```

I'm running `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: Which is why `which` is basically useless...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first one is the `bash`'s own builtin keyword `time` (compiled with `bash`), and the second one is the external executable `time` (`/usr/bin/time`, comes with the `time` package).

Also, `which` can't show the shell's builtin commands or keywords as it just searches through `PATH`, you need to use `type` for that. Being a shell builtin itself, `type` can additionally check for shell's internal entities (and also `PATH`), so you can spot the difference by:

```
type -a time
```

Here:

```
$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
```

The first one will be executed if you just use `time`. You can also get which is being executed by just using `type` (without `-a`):

```
type time
```

The `-a` tells `type` to search in shell's internal entities and also in `PATH` i.e. search in all possible sources.

If for some reason you need the external one, use any one of:

```
\time
"time"
'time'
command time
```

Comment: ah ,I see,  so `which` does not consider builtins? And I should always check with `type -a` first. Actually, it seems `type` is superior to `which` because it outputs location `/usr/bin/time` as well

Comment: @xaxa Yeah, check my edits.

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer! What is `which` useful for then?

Comment: @xaxa When you just want to search through `PATH`. Note that, the same can be achieved by `type` using `-P` e.g. `type -P time`.

Comment: @xaxa `type` is indeed superior --- if you're using bash. Another shell may not have either the `type` bulitin, or the `time` builtin.

Comment: @jpaugh good point

Comment: @jpaugh Not quite right. POSIX allows `time` to be external only but not `type`,  `type` is available in all POSIX compliant shells.

Comment: @heemayl Non-POSIX shells may not have `type` though. On `csh` and `tcsh`, not only `type` doesn't exist, but `which` is different and tells you about built-in commands.

Comment: @heemayl Your post was especially informative, as I've never used `type` before. Since I'll never go near a non-POSIX shell, it's good news that POSIX specifies it.

Answer (score 4):

Another difference between the builtin and external utilities is, that Bash's builtin `time` [will time complete pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) or calls to shell functions (apparently even loops, but the manual doesn't seem to promise that). The external `time` cannot, since being outside the shell, doesn't know about the surrounding code.

```
bash$ time echo blah | sleep 3
real    0m3.002s
...
bash$ /usr/bin/time echo blah | sleep 3
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU 
...
bash$ time for x in 1 2 3 ; do sleep 1 ; done
real    0m3.006s
...
```

While time is [specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html) in the standard, it's left unspecified how it should act in a pipeline, so a more powerful internal implementation like this is possible.